# How does melting ice change the mass of the ocean?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, mass, oceanography

In the paper, [Ocean Bottom Deformation Due To Present-Day Mass Redistribution and Its Impact on Sea Level Observations](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/2017GL075419/full), the authors state that:

> Due to changes in the land ice mass balance and land hydrology, the
>   oceans have gained mass over the past decades (Chambers et al., 2016),
>   which results in an increase of the total load on the ocean bottom.

and

> We use realistic estimates of mass redistribution from ice mass loss and land water storage
>
> The largest differences can be found in the **Arctic Ocean**: due to the location close to many **melt sources**, the relative sea level in the Arctic drops, while geocentric sea level rises,

I don't understand how melting ice increases the mass of the ocean? Are they referring to ice normally residing on land, not the ice shelves that rest in the ocean?

Comment: Presumably, ice isn't treated as part of the oceans so when it melts the ocean mass increases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are they referring to ice normally residing on land, not the ice shelves that rest in the ocean?

Yes, glaciers and such. Remember Antarctica, Siberia, Northern Canada, and Greenland aren't floating.